# Animate Bootstrap 4 card to center of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get the following effect:

- Have a few `bootstrap 4` cards displayed as a grid
- When clicking on a `button` from inside a card, it should `animate` as follows: 
  rotate 180 degrees, get to a specific height/width (from 400px - 350px to entire screen) and position itself in the center of the screen.

For now, I know how to get the rotation with

```
rotateY(180deg)
```

when I click on a button:

```
$('#enlarge').on('click',
    function() {
        $('#kidCard').toggleClass("flipper");
    });
```

having that rotation set in the flipper class, but I'm not able to get the rest of my desired animation. 
Can someone help me with this?

**Update**:

My current html:

```
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3 kid-card" id="kidCard">
        <div class="card-header">
            Child name: ...
            <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor: pointer"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body kid-card-content">
            <div class="kid-card-content-image">
                <img src="~/Content/download.png" width="110" height="110"/>
            </div>
            <div class="kid-card-content-description">
                <p class="card-text">
                    Age: ...
                </p>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Gender: ...
                </p>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Height: ...
                </p>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Weight: ...
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="enlarge">Edit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

having js file:

```
$('#enlarge').on('click',
    function() {
        $('#kidCard').toggleClass("flipper");
    });
```

and for now, this is my css file:

```
.flip-container .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipper {
    transition: 2s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}
```

In the transform I also tried `translateY(calc(50vh - 50%)) translateX(calc(50vh - 50%))` in order to position it in the center of the screen, but it doesn't work.

**SOLUTION:**

I finally got it working with the following code (thank you all for contributing):

.js file:

```
$.fn.toggleZindex= function() {
            const $this = $(this);
            if($this.css("z-index")=="auto") {
                $this.css("z-index", "99999");
            }else {
                $this.css("z-index", "auto");
            }

            return this;
        };

        $.fn.animateRotate = function(angle, duration, easing, startingDegree, complete) {
            var args = $.speed(duration, easing, complete);
            var step = args.step;
            return this.each(function(i, e) {
                args.complete = $.proxy(args.complete, e);
                args.step = function(now) {
                    $.style(e, 'transform', 'rotateY(' + now + 'deg)');
                    if (step) return step.apply(e, arguments);
                };

                $({ deg: startingDegree}).animate({deg: angle}, args);
            });
        };

        function getRotationDegrees(obj) {
            const matrix = obj.css("-webkit-transform") ||
                obj.css("-moz-transform")    ||
                obj.css("-ms-transform")     ||
                obj.css("-o-transform")      ||
                obj.css("transform");
            if(matrix !== 'none') {
                const values = matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
                const a = values[0];
                const b = values[1];
                var angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(b, a) * (180/Math.PI));
            } else { var angle = 0; }
            return (angle < 0) ? angle + 360 : angle;
        }

        $('.editChildButton').on('click',
            function () {
                const idOfChild = $(this).attr('ChildId');
                const tc = $(window).height() / 2 - $('.item').height() / 2 - $(this.closest('.item')).offset().top;
                const lc = $(window).width() / 2 - $('.item').width() / 2 - $(this.closest('.item')).offset().left;

                $(this.closest('.item')).toggleZindex();

                const startingDegree = getRotationDegrees($(this.closest('.item')));

                $(this.closest('.item')).animateRotate(startingDegree == 0 ? 180 : 0, 2000, 'swing', startingDegree);

                $(this.closest('.item')).animate({
                    left: lc,
                    top: tc
                }, 2000, function () {
                    $(this.closest('.item')).css({ position: 'fixed', left: $(this.closest('.item')).offset().left, top: $(this.closest('.item')).offset().top });
                    $(this.closest('.item')).animate({
                        left: 0,
                        top: 0,
                        width: '100vw',
                        height: '100vh'
                    },2000);
                });
            });
```

Comment: can you create a plunkr? I don't see `#Card` in your markup.

Comment: I fixed the code. Just read after my update

Comment: it's worth making a working demo plunkr/jsfiddle as this is one of the those questions that requires a bit a fiddling, you'll have a better chance of getting a good answer this way.

Comment: After trying to reproduce your problem: https://codepen.io/Carr1005/pen/rvevgq 
I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: are you trying something like this - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vjGjvE to center content

Comment: @Carr That card is in a grid in my project which is not in the center of the screen. Whatever I tried it didn't animate to the center. I also want the card to come to center of the screen and also be full screen, because I want to redirect with an effect - but that's another thing.

Comment: @NagaSaiA No, I'm trying to center the whole card (which in my project is not centered - is inside a grid)

Comment: The problem is that the card is not starting from top:0 left:0....it's inside a grid so transform: translate(calc(50vh - 50%),calc(50vh - 50%)) doesn't bring it to the actual center of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, to achieve such effect, CSS animations are not enough. The easiest way would be to change positioning to fixed, put card on middle and scale it as you want. Take a look on a [DEMO](https://codepen.io/mcekiera/pen/bMgadx).

Of course it is just example, for just one card, but it should work with multiple cards in various positions. On click card:

1. rotates 180deg (though I don't understand why 180),
2. move to center of viewport,
3. change size to fill all viewport,

animation works both ways.

HTML:

```
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3 kid-card" id="kidCard">
        <div class="card-header">
            Child name: ...
            <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor: pointer"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body kid-card-content">
            <div class="kid-card-content-image">
                <img src="~/Content/download.png" width="110" height="110"/>
            </div>
            <div class="kid-card-content-description">
                <p class="card-text">
                    Age: ...
                </p>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Gender: ...
                </p>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Height: ...
                </p>
                <p class="card-text">
                    Weight: ...
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="enlarge">Edit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flip-container {
  width: 400px;
}

.flip-container .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card {
  transition-duration: 2s;
}

.movement {
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotateY(180deg);
}
```

JS:

```
var element = $('#kidCard');
var w = element.width();
var h = element.height();

$('#enlarge').on('click',
  function() {
    if(element.hasClass('movement')) {
      element.removeClass('movement');
      element.css({width: w, height: h, top: 0, left: 0});
    } else {
      var left = element.offset().left;
      var top = element.offset().top;
      element.css({position: 'fixed', left: left, top: top, width: w, height: h});
      element.addClass('movement');
      element.css({width: '100vw', height: '100vh', top: '50%', left: '50%'});
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll check your code tomorrow, but it seems that this is what I need - thank you. Why I need 180? Well I'm trying to have a blank 'back' of the card that will expand full screen and it will 'mask' a redirect.

Comment: I added my final solution to the question if someone needs its, but I'll give you the points as your answer helped me the most. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your specific situation but if you could find a way to use `position: absolute`, it would make it a lot easier when moving the cards around.

When positioning a div in the center of the screen, the important thing is to know how wide and high your element is at the moment of the transition. If your use case allows you to set those dimensions manually then you are set, you simply use:

```
left: calc(50% - manuallySetWidth);
top: calc(50% - manuallySetHeight);
```

but if you cannot manually set them then you need to find a alternate mechanism. To be honest, the variant I'm proposing here is something that uses [a somewhat new addition to CSS](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/) (which is why it's very likely there are other simpler solutions for this) and [here is apost](https://eager.io/blog/communicating-between-javascript-and-css-with-css-variables/) that helped me getting started with those.

I commented the code to explain the proceedings

HIH

```js
//set these vars to use them in css
$('#kidCard')[0].style.setProperty('--width', $('#kidCard').width()+'px');
$('#kidCard')[0].style.setProperty('--height', $('#kidCard').height()+'px');

$('#enlarge').on('click',
  function() {
    $('#kidCard').toggleClass("flipper");
    $('body').toggleClass("shady");
});
```

```css
body{
  transition: 1s;
}

body.shady{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  
}

.flip-container .card {
  left: 0;/*manually set each card's left and top in order for the translation to work smoothly, */
  top: 0;/*if you have them in a grid you could use i and j to do this */
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: 1s;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
}

.flip-container .card.flipper {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
  left: calc(50% - var(--width)/2); /*use the variables set in js*/
  top: calc(50% - var(--height)/2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip-container">
   <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3 kid-card" id="kidCard">
    <div class="card-header">
     Child name: ...
     <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor: pointer"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body kid-card-content">
     <div class="kid-card-content-image">
      <img src="~/Content/download.png" width="110" height="110"/>
     </div>
     <div class="kid-card-content-description">
      <p class="card-text">
       Age: ...
      </p>
      <p class="card-text">
       Gender: ...
      </p>
      <p class="card-text">
       Height: ...
      </p>
      <p class="card-text">
       Weight: ...
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
     <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="enlarge">Edit</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I realised that css is not enough for what I need. As I understand, your answer would work for part of my desired effect (center the card). Thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this is to set a `width` on your flipper class, then set the margins to auto. Setting a `width` value and `margin:auto` will center a block level element.

```
.flip-container .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipper {
    transition: 2s;
    margin: auto;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/Lt0qq207/1/)

Or if you would prefer a flex box solution something like this works:

```
.flip-container .flipper {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flipper {
    transition: 2s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}

.body-flipper {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

body, html{
  width:100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  margin:0;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/Lt0qq207/4/)